# Blacklist [restart]

Tags: discussion, tags, blocklist-request

[restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restart) is problematic because it's most often used for Questions related to software restarts, while the wiki claims:

> This refers to the process where a computer's power state is systematically (and preferably gracefully) changed to a powered-off state and then automatically powered back on without intervention from the user.

If we indeed need a tag about hardware restarts (which I doubt), it needs to be named something else.

Comment: Rather than blacklist it, maybe you should submit a modified description for the tag's wiki?

Comment: I do not find the concept of software restarts worthy of own tag.

Answer (score -1):

There are currently around 600 questions using this tag. A quick scan down the list shows me that it is generally being used within context - i.e. the questions are about restarting *something*.

Personally I think the tag is fine. `restart` is the process of stopping something and then starting it again. This action can be applied to anything that is capable of running or operating, or has more than a single state. So by definition this includes hardware and software - there is no need to differentiate between them. The other tags should provide the context.

This would indicate that blacklisting it is the wrong action to take - a tag shouldn't be eliminated simply because its wiki entry is incomplete. Instead you should:

1. expand the tag wiki description to include programmatic restarts of applications and/or services
2. retag (remove the tag) questions that are using it in a way that doesn't satisfy the modified wiki description

If you do step 1, you should then find that there are very few questions in need of step 2.

Comment: There is a just one follower, which is a good indicator of its usefulness.

Comment: The concept of [tag:software-restarts] does not seem like a concept people would be interested in, right? That lots of people use it is no a indicator that it is useful. The tags people use are often questionable. Examples: [tag:checking], [tag:running], [tag:generation], [tag:relations], [tag:paid], etc.). I don't see how the concept of software restarting is better than one of these.

Answer (score -2):

I've edited the wiki

> This refers to the process where a software program or system is
>   systematically (and preferably gracefully) shut down then
>   automatically invoked to full functionality without intervention from
>   the user.

Comment: Does that not mean [tag:hardware-restart] should now be created?

Comment: @Tshepang - Last I heard hardware could be considered a system.  In any case as slugster pointed out, there are no questions on SO about hardware restarts -- at least that I could find.

Comment: I was actually thinking of [tag:reboot] concept.